# Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2]

Tags: android

It was worked and compiled perfectly the gradle,But When I tried to run on android emulator ,it appear this problem :

> Error:(25, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments
>   [com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2] on object of
>   type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.Please install the Android
>   Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.

Even I tried to cut `compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'` statement and I compiled the left statement of implementation `'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'` but it shows the error in this statement .It seems the `gradle` corrupted

The dependencies was worked perfectly but now it is not work.

[image: Error]
[image: gradle]

Comment: Better add the error and dependency in the question, rather than adding them as links since links will most likely expire and future people coming here won't be able to see them.

Comment: Ok I will. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a minor typo, because you are using a wrong code:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'}
```

Remove the `}` from it, so it will be like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

Comment: @Kaleb: Great!. If my answer solve your problem, you can set it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Ohh yah, that was my problem. It works fine now. Thank you very much @ישו אוהב אותך